# jxBrowser add key listener for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jxbrowser

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013075-keyboard-mouse-events provides an example for adding key listener to swing BrowserView, however there is no equivalent key listener for javafx BrowserView. Is there another way to add listener for javafx?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use:

```
 view.setOnKeyPressed(event ->{
            System.out.println(event.getCode());
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method before, but I was using the event class as a parameter and I wasn't able to find the key info. After switching javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent, it works.